# Mount: permission denied

Tags: mount

I'm following a tutorial for configuring a server, but I had to give a command that is not working.

```
mount -o remount /

root @ hsj1: ~ # mount -o remount /
mount: permission denied
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you post the link to the tutorial?

Comment: http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Configurando-Servidor-WEB-Completo-Apache2-PostfixCourier-Bind9-ISPConfig-Roundcube-Webmail/?pagina=3

Comment: Did you executed it as root? I executed as root with `sudo mount -o remount /` and it don't gave me any problem. However, you can get the same effect rebooting the computer.

Comment: We performed by root yes. Only access via root.

Comment: root@hsj1:~# sudo mount -o remount /
mount: permission denied

Answer (score 0):

> There are several things that might cause this. either the command was not run as root user or you use a virtual server were a remount of the / filesystem is not allowed.

Your case seems to be the second (You are using a virtual server were a remount of the / filesystem is not allowed)

You can replace this command with a reboot.

Source: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/ispconfig-installation-mount-o-remount-question.64840/

Comment: So I just restart and continue with the tutorial commands? And yes, it is a virtual server hired.

Comment: When you restart the system, you are unmounting all the partitions and mounting them again. I think that with a reboot is sufficient.

Comment: - _Did it work?_